# Check if a variable is in the scope or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a object "objCR" is present in the current scope or not.
I tried using below code.

```
if(objCR == null)
alert("object is not defined");
```

Let me know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) operator:

```
if(typeof objCR == "undefined")
   alert("objCR is not defined");
```

Comment: ..yes, beat me to it as well!

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question as I understand it because `objCR` could easily be declared within the current scope but still be undefined. For example, `var objCR;` would do that.

Comment: This will detect if the variable exists in any scope. It doesn't it to just the current function scope. I don't think there's any way to limit that variable to just the current scope.

Comment: Thank you for this recipe. One correction: I prefer the strict equality operator, '===' (or '!==' in my own use case).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof objCR=="undefined"){
    alert("objCR is undefined");
} else {
    alert("objCR is defined");
};
```

`(!objCR)` will return true if `objCR` is a boolean equal to `false`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, using a `typeof` check will get you some of the way there:

```
if (typeof objCR == "undefined") {
    alert("objCR is undefined");
}
```

However, this won't distinguish between `objCR` existing and being undefined (as would be the case if it had been declared but not assigned to, e.g. using `var objCR;`) and `objCR` never having been declared anywhere in the scope chain, which I think is what you actually want. If you want to be sure that no `objCR` variable has even been declared, you could use `try/catch` as follows:

```
try {
    objCR; // ReferenceError is thrown if objCR is undeclared
} catch (ex) {
    alert("objCR has not been declared");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the obvious:

```
if (objCR==undefined) ...
```

Comment: undefined is a JavaScript keyword ("The keyword 'undefined' indicates that a variable has no value or does not exist. This is different from null, but they are generally considered equal")

Comment: better to use `typeof`, as javascript doesn't protect the `undefined` keyword - you can actually have code which sets `undefined = 42`(!) which would break your comparison

Comment: `(objCR==undefined)` fails in IE6 at least if `objCR` is undefined. Use `typeof` to be safe.

Comment: The problems with this are: first, that you will get a `ReferenceError` in all browsers if `objCR` has never been declared; second, a comparison with `undefined` using `==` will also return `true` if `objCR` is `null`; third, that a variable that has been declared but not assigned a value will be undefined, and fourth, that `undefined` is not a reserved word and its value can be altered.

Answer (score 0):

I always have this to be safe:

```
if(typeof objCR == "undefined" || objCR == null)
   alert("object is not defined or null");
```

Comment: `null` is definitely different from `undefined`, so this as it stands is *wrong*.

Comment: @Andrzej sorry I don't understand why it's wrong.. I'm double checking that's all. Isn't it possible for something to be defined but null? If you mean the message, it's now fixed.